# Cannot Assign a value of type CGPoint to a value of Type CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code. I'm trying to make a small tile game and this is the function to randomise the tiles location. The problem i'm having here is to assign the randLocation to the imageview.

```
var imageViewCentersCopy : NSMutableArray = imageViewsCenters.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
var randLocationIndex : Int
var randLocation : CGPoint

for imageView in self.imageViews {
    randLocationIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageViewCentersCopy.count)))
    randLocation = imageViewCentersCopy.objectAtIndex(randLocationIndex).CGPointValue()

    println("\(self.imageViews)")

    imageView.center = randLocation
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `imageView`?

Comment: But what type Xcode shows you?

Comment: Sorry. I just checked here, the type is AnyObject

Comment: `(imageView as! UIImageView).center = randLocation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the typecast to avoid that problem

```
(imageView as! UIImageView).center = randLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not very expedient to use the coordinates in your randomizing logic. These are really two separate problems. Try to think of a simpler model, then develop the placement logic.

For example, you could just randomize the order of the tiles in a flat array.

Then you simply iterate through the array, calculate the correct coordinates with some simple row and column algorithm (based on the index) and place the tiles in their correct position.

This, too, is MVC.

E.g. assuming 9 tiles for a 3x3 grid:

```
for var x = 0; x < randomTiles.count; x++ {
    let row = x / 3
    let column = x % 3
    let point = CGPointMake(10 + column * 20, 10 + row * 20)
    // assign the tile's center
}
```